# How to display a class from another class in PHP

Tags: php

How to display a class from another class in PHP ?

```
 class Layout {
      public $var;

      public function __construct() {
           $this->var = 'test';
      }

      public function __toString() {
           return $this->var;
      }
 }

 class Template {
      private $var_layout;

      public function __construct() {
           $obj = new Layout;
           $this->var_layout = $obj;
      }

      public function __toString() {
           return $this->var_layout;
      }
 }

 $template = new Template();

 echo($template);
```

Error message: Method Template::__toString() must return a string value

Please help, thank you very much..

Answer (score 3):

`return $this->var_layout;` in the `Template` class does not return a string, it returns an object. Make it return a string by calling the `__toString()` method of that object explicitly.

Comment: Indeed. Either `$this->var_layout->__toString();`, or `return (string)$this->var_layout;` would also work (with the benefit of no fatal error if it's not an object/has no `__toString()` method.